# bash function preserving tab completion

Tags: bash, makefile, pipe, alias, gnu-make

I put the function

```
make_color() {
    make $1 | ccze -A
}
```

in `.bashrc` to get colored make output. His works fine, but `make`'s tab-completion for selecting targets is lost. Is there any way to preserve the tab-completion of the command in the function, or something else I could do to achieve tab completion and pipe?

Comment: Run this in your shell or add in your `~/.bashrc`: `complete -F _make make_color`

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your `~/.bashrc` or run in your local shell:

```
complete -F _make make_color
```

The function name `_make` may be different in your case.
You can get the name using:

```
$ complete -p make
complete -F _make make
```

Comment: Hm, _make didn't work and for some reason `complete -p make` returns `bash: complete: make: no completion specification`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Sometimes, bash loads it at run time. Type `make<tab><tab>`. at THIS point bash loads some completion routines. After that, `complete -p make` would work. and `complete -F _make make_color` should work too.

Comment: After `make<tab><tab>` the command `complete -p make` worked! But still no luck with the completion of `make_color`. After a few tabs the terminal is frozen for a while, so SOMETHING is going on at least.

Comment: It's lazy loading of the completion. Instead of loading all the shell completion at the start, bash has a way to load them on-demand. There is a way to force load a completion without having to press `make<TAB><TAB>`. I had it in some file. I misplaced it.