# How do you get make completion to load before using make+tab?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, autocomplete

Following on from this question:

[bash-function-preserving-tab-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448535/bash-function-preserving-tab-completion)

It shows that by adding into .bashrc:

```
mj() {
    make -j10 $@
}
complete -F _make mj
```

When I run `mj <tab>` I get "function _make not found"

But then when I run `make <tab>` (which loads the completion for make) then when I run `mj <tab>` it works fine.

So how can I force make completion to load withouth having to manually type `make <tab>` first?

Comment: Here `make` is the command or you have a wrapper written over the command to build files?

Comment: @Inian My new command (function) in .bashrc is `mj` which itself calls `make` inside. The problem appears to be that make's completion function only gets loaded once you run `make + tab` i.e. when you invoke make's tab-completion. Until you do that the function `_make` is not defined so my line `compete -F _make mj` fails until `_make` has been defined (or sourced?). I want to know how I can force this in side bashrc (or elsewhere) so that I don't have to do it manually... does that answer your question? (the wrapper is the function `mj()`)

Answer (score 0):

To have completion functions working they must be loaded in your profile first. Something like:

```
if [ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi
```

Also make sure that `shopt -q progcomp` is true, and completion script for make (`/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`) exists on your computer.